# How to put 3 different image with order in tableview cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a imageview in tableview cell and I have 3 different image.

**What I'm trying to do :**

my cell should look like:

```
img1
img2
img3
img1
img2
img3
img1
.
.
```

.
how can i do this order ? Sorry for my bad english :)

**here is my cellforrowat**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let jlist = self.joinAllAllowedInnoList, !jlist.isEmpty {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JoinCell", for: indexPath) as! JoinCell

            //--

            cell.delegate = self
            cell.indexPath = indexPath



            //--
            if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
                cell.thubnailImageView.image = UIImage(named:"thumb1")

            }
            else {
                cell.thubnailImageView.image = UIImage(named:"thumb2")
            }

            cell.participationEndDate.text = jlist[indexPath.row].joinEnd
            cell.titleLabel.text = jlist[indexPath.row].shortDesc

            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = .clear
            cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
            cell.textLabel?.text = "nodataavaiable".localized()
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create a custom cell with 3 image views.

Comment: no,I mean if(indexpath.row % 2  == 0 ){ cell.imageview.image = uiimage (named : "img1")

Comment: Update your question with your `cellForRowAt` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
let row = indexPath.row + 1
if row % 3 == 0 {
    // Img3
}
if (row + 1) % 3 == 0 {
    // Img2
}
if (row + 2) % 3 == 0 {
    // Img1
}
```

Comment: This is way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work. It's just far more complicated than it should be and the logic is actually fairly confusing. There is no need for any addition and there is no need for more than one modulo operator. And it's poor practice to use three separate `if` statement when only one can be true. Use `if/else`. It is clearer and more efficient.

Comment: I just answered the question. The debats about code clearness should be at other place. However i can change the answer with one modulo operator. Do you want it?

Comment: You may do whatever you wish. I was simply providing constructive feedback to future readers of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple logic. First, put your three images in an array:

```
let images = [UIImage(named:"thumb1"), UIImage(named:"thumb2"), UIImage(named:"thumb3")]
```

Make that a property of your view controller.

Now in `cellForRowAt` you simply do:

```
cell.thubnailImageView.image = images[indexPath.row % 3]
```

That's it.

---

If you don't want an array, you can do something simple like:

```
let imgNum = indexPath.row % 3
if imgNum == 0 {
    // use Img1
} else if imgNum == 1 {
    // use Img2
} else {
    // use Img3
}
```